# Verify Domain Ownership for Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace

I've got Google Apps set up on my domain. Recently, I've moved my domain from GoDaddy to Hover. The transfer process has just completed and I'm currently changing the necessary DNS settings.

As per the [instructions](http://help.hover.com/entries/21226772-how-to-google-apps-domain-verification-and-mx-records) on Hover's site on verifying my domain, I went back to my Google Apps dashboard. Based from this [instructional video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sce3p2L4rq0&feature=player_detailpage#t=170s) by Google, I navigated to the Setup tab on the control panel. However, the 'Verify domain ownership' sub-tree is missing on the page.

[image]

I watched the video again, and tried to modify the latter part of the URL from `WELCOME_AND_VERIFY` to `VERIFY_DOMAIN_OWNERSHIP_TASK`, but it just goes to the 'Users and groups' section instead.

In addition, on the Settings tab and Email section, it says that there's no MX records found for my domain.

[image]

I've successfully changed other settings (MX, CNAME), but I'm currently stucked on this step.

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Google Apps account was already verified whilst you were at GoDaddy you don't need to re-verify after a move to Hover (and hence can't).

p.s. You may have missed a redaction in your image in the location bar.

Comment: Thanks! I've also forgotten to include my issue with MX records not being found.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the MX records via Hover not in the Google Apps interface:

http://help.hover.com/entries/21204757-how-to-edit-dns-records-a-cname-mx-txt-and-srv
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125